# Marker in an Area border google map API

Tags: api, google-maps

I've been mixing Marker and Border codes to try on the case that ""Multi-markers in a Area border" as code below.
However,I don't know the reason why it can not loaded successfully while each code has been OK as my attached pictures:

- [AreaBorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKr1J.jpg)
- [MultiMarkers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZ2l2.jpg)

Some experts here can give me some advices please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Complex Marker Icons</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

    #map_canvas {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div id="map_cord"></div>
  <script>
    // The following example creates complex markers to indicate beaches near
    // Sydney, NSW, Australia. Note that the anchor is set to (0,32) to correspond
    // to the base of the flagpole.

    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {
          lat: 21.040735,
          lng: 105.807015
        }
      });
      var pVinhPhuc = [
        new google.maps(lat: 21.047552, lng: 105.806087),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.047313, lng: 105.808452),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.045842, lng: 105.811349),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.043028, lng: 105.814561),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.042071, lng: 105.814305),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.041575, lng: 105.814048),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.041225, lng: 105.813536),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.041078, lng: 105.813102),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.038558, lng: 105.812649),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.037970, lng: 105.813339),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.037142, lng: 105.814994),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.035726, lng: 105.814561),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.036204, lng: 105.810600),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.037823, lng: 105.810541),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.037687, lng: 105.806425),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.039324, lng: 105.806387),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.040090, lng: 105.806201),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.040337, lng: 105.806948),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.040770, lng: 105.806901),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.042956, lng: 105.805904),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.047111, lng: 105.805951),
        new google.maps(lat: 21.047587, lng: 105.806090)
      ];

      var pVinhPhucHightlight = new google.maps.Polygon({

        //DRAW THE POLYGON OR POLYLINE

        paths: pVinhPhuc,
        strokeColor: "#6666FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.6,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#6666FF",
        fillOpacity: 0.2
      });
      setMarkers(map);

    }

    // Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
    // order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
    var beaches = [
      ['MrTuan Apartment', 21.040735, 105.807015, 4],
      ['Milk 01', 21.045747, 105.807389, 5],
      ['Milk 02', 21.039538, 105.811123, 3],
      ['Milk 03', 21.038597, 105.809428, 2],
      ['Milk 04', 21.042943, 105.809685, 1]
    ];


    function setMarkers(map) {

      // Adds markers to the map.
      // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
      // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.
      // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
      // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
      var image = {
        url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
        // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
        size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
        // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
      };
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
      // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
      // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
      var shape = {
        coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
        type: 'poly'
      };
      for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
        var beach = beaches[i];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: beach[1],
            lng: beach[2]
          },
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          shape: shape,
          title: beach[0],
          zIndex: beach[3]
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```